# Compare column between two tables (greater and equal to)

Tags: sql

I have two table, and i want to compare the two column from those two table. The column reflow in table f_product must greater and equal to column lreflow in table f_line.  The coding that I used is

```
SELECT f_product.oiv,f_product.product,f_product.passive,f_product.pitch,f_product.reflow,f_line.lreflow,f_product.spi,f_product.scomp,f_product.pallet,f_product.printer,f_line.line  
FROM f_product,f_line  
WHERE f_product.passive=f_line.passive  
AND f_product.pitch=f_line.pitch  
AND f_product.spi=f_line.spi  
AND f_product.pallet=f_line.pallet  
AND f_product.printer=f_line.printer   
AND f_product.reflow >= f_line.lreflow  
AND oiv='PMLE4720A' .
```

However, the result display out did not compare out the column data in between f_product.reflow and f_line.lreflow. For example, the result still list out the result of reflow=8 and lreflow=10 where reflow is less than the value of lreflow. 
Is that my sql coding have any error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is Oracle? Sometimes it gets confused by the ambiguity between real where clauses and an implicit join using a where. I would recast it into ansi sql joins:

```
SELECT
.....
FROM
f_product a INNER JOIN f_line b ON 
(a.passive = b.passive AND
 a.pitch =b.pitch AND
 a.spi=b.spi AND
 a.pallet=b.pallet)
where oiv='PMLE4720A'
and  a.reflow >= b.lreflow
```

Assuming the relationship between product and line is such that it makes sense to jion on these four fields...

Comment: well... it still doesn't work on, the result display out still same as the result that i tried before which the table line reflow that more than table product reflow will come out all together.

Comment: That's strange. Can you post some data from the tables somewhere?

Comment: f_product: oiv-varchar2(50) not null,product-varchar2(50),passive-varchar2(10),pitch-varchar2(10),reflow-varchar2(10),spi-varchar2(10)...
f_line: line-varchar2(50) not null, passive-varchar2(10), pitch-varchar2(10),lreflow-varchar2(10)...
and the result display out like:
oiv      reflow      lreflow
1          8           10
2          8            8
3          8            7